# Convert the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss to datetime in javascript which is acceptable by getTime() function

Tags: javascript, datetime, format, datetime-format, time-format

I have a date in the format **yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss** and I want to convert it to datetime format in such a way that if the result is evaluated via **getTime()** method, it will return number of milliseconds. For now, the method I have tried is throwing the error : ***Uncaught TypeError: dt.getTime is not a function*** where ***dt*** is the resultant date. Please state a way to achieve this using javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I have a date in the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`. Is it a `date` or `string` ?

Comment: would you consider using MomentJS or not?

Comment: @Pugazh It is in string format 
@ Marek Urbanowicz If there is an option to achieve this without using MomentJS it would be better. Otherwise plz suggest the MomentJS way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your date is string, you should initialize new Date object with your time string as parameter. getTime() is method of Date object. Note that it may not work in all browsers.

```
var date = new Date('2016-11-09T18:00:01');
alert(date.getTime())
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rxo5zz71/